# ios - UITableViewCell display wrong data when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifierNormal = @"CellNormal";
static NSString *CellIdentifierTracking = @"CellTracking";

switch (self.mapState) {
    case MapStateNormal:
    {
//            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierNormal];
//            if (cell == nil) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierNormal];
//            }
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"abc"];
        return cell;
    }
    case MapStateTracking:
    {
//            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierTracking];
//            if (cell == nil) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierTracking];
//            }
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [cell.textLabel setText:@"Lorem ipsum"];
        } else {
            NSURL *url = [LoremIpsum URLForPlaceholderImageFromService:LoremIpsumPlaceholderImageServicePlaceKittenCom
                                                             withWidth:1024
                                                                height:1024];
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuButton"]];
           }
        return cell;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
return nil;
}
```

This piece of code works fine but not the best practice because I re-create `UITableViewCell` everytime. It display like this:

[image: Correct Display]

However, when I uncomment those lines above to enable `dequeueReusableCell` then the table shows its cells with errors like this (the yellow part is my code):

[image] [image]

You can see that there's an `UIImage` in first row and text in some rows below while I clearly didn't set it in my code.

What could I do to fix this ? or should I stick with the first method ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should really re-use the table view cells, because it is a lot of overhead if you recreate them all the time, i.e. the out-commented code is right.
Next, the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW33) say: "The table view's delegate in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should always reset all content when reusing a cell."
If you do not reset the content, it will be shown again.
So I suggest that you set

```
cell.imageView.image = nil;
```

in your `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Comment: ok thanks. I though reset content is an automatic operation that executes everytime when the cell is going to be reused.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `[cell.textLabel setText:@""];` for each cell you dont't want to display any text. Cells are reused with the previous text, so you need to clear it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, clear the cell if it `cell != nil`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifierNormal = @"CellNormal";
static NSString *CellIdentifierTracking = @"CellTracking";

switch (self.mapState) {
    case MapStateNormal:
    {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierNormal];
            if (cell == nil) {
                UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierNormal];
            } else {
                [cell.textLabel setText:@""];
                [cell.imageView setImage:nil];
            }
            ...
        return cell;
    }

    case MapStateTracking:
    {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierTracking];
            if (cell == nil) {
                UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierTracking];
            } else {
                [cell.textLabel setText:@""];
                [cell.imageView setImage:nil];
            }
            ....
        return cell;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
return nil;
}
```